# Posting a complex object through ajax along with other simple types

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I know that this question has been asked like a hundred times, but I can't figure it out.

I have an ajax call like

```
function saveBox()
{
    var postModel = createBoxPostModel();

    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        url: '@(Url.BuildAction<IncomingGoodsVerificationController>(x => x.SaveWorkUnitForBox(null, null, null)))',
        data: { jsonPostModel: postModel, boxItemKey: boxItemKey, itemKey: itemKey },

        success: function (data, status) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            hideLoader();
            displayErrorMessagePopup('Error in saving box! ', errorThrown, 'error-msgs');
        }
    });
}
```

and the controller method is like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveWorkUnitForBox(NewWorkUnitBoxModel postModel, string boxItemKey, string itemKey)
{
    ....
}
```

The `NewWorkUnitBoxModel` is

```
public class NewWorkUnitBoxModel
{
    public NewWorkUnitBoxModel();

    public string AlternativeWorkUnitNumer { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public int ChooseType { get; set; }
    public decimal? GrossWeight { get; set; }
    public long IdCompany { get; set; }
    public long? IdPackagingType { get; set; }
    public long? IdWorkUnitSubType { get; set; }
    public decimal? NetWeight { get; set; }
    public string Tone { get; set; }
    public decimal? Volume { get; set; }
    public long? WorkUnitNumber2 { get; set; }
}
```

and yet when the controller action is called is either null or the object has no value for each of its properties.

I tried several ways:

- `data: { jsonPostModel: postModel, boxItemKey: boxItemKey, itemKey: itemKey }`
- `data: { jsonPostModel: JSON.stringify(postModel), boxItemKey: boxItemKey, itemKey: itemKey }`
- Putting all action parameters inside a *request* class

None of these worked. Client-side the model is loaded correctly, and by using `ModelBinders` I also looked inside the `HtmlRequest` and data had arrived on the server. I only solved with changing the type to a string and deserialize it inside the action.

How can I make it automatically deserialize the model?

Comment: try this: `data: { postModel: postModel, boxItemKey: boxItemKey, itemKey: itemKey }`

Comment: update your url to  `@Url.Action("SaveWorkUnitForBox","YourConroller") `

Comment: You need to stringify the data - `data: JSon.stringify{ postModel: postModel, boxItemKey: boxItemKey, itemKey: itemKey }),` and add the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` option. And note its `postModel` not `jsonPostModel` (your method does not have a parameter named `jsonPostModel`)

Comment: @MahbuburRahman I forgot to change it but yours is what I tried initially

Comment: @sepehr the one I'm using is an extension method of mine, the call arrives on the server so that's not a url problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke same as for MahbuburRahman, I forgot to change it but that's what I tried. I'll try your solution asap